# Install software on Windows from Linux live usb

Tags: linux, windows, windows-7, windows-server-2008, admin

I'm a (noob) administrator of a little network. For business purpose I have some Windows 7 PCs and a 2008 Server. 
While doing the setup, something has come to my mind: is it possible for a user without high privileges to install some kind of software using a live usb?
Ok, it's possible to reset admin password, manage partitions, etc. but can someone do that without change admin settings? just putting software in admin's (or else) directory and editing the windows register?

Thanks!

Comment: I found an interesting resource:
[is-it-possible-to-install-software-on-windows-from-a-linux-live-usb][1]


  [1]: http://superuser.com/questions/682851/is-it-possible-to-install-software-on-windows-from-a-linux-live-usb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say: Yes. If someone manages to boot the machine from a live usb-stick, cd, dvd or whatever, he can:

- Mount the disk with the windows-installation.
- Read and Write to that disk.
- Install software on that disk: Installing software is not much more than copying files from one place to another.
- Possibly modify the registry: The registry must also be stored somewhere on the disc. If the user can access that file, he can modify it and therefore modify the registry (its another question if this are valid manipulations).

Comment: is there any resource referring editing the register about "manual software installing"?

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent access to the harddisk by using Windows 7 BitLocker.
It is not possible to mount the drive from a live system when it is activated:

Here is a guide how to do this:
[BitLocker Guide](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd835565(v=ws.10).aspx)